# Subgroups of $U(n)$ isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, direct-sum

Let $U(n)$ to be the set of all positive integers less then $n$ and relatively prime to $n$. Then $U(n)$ is a group under multiplication modulo $n$.

A. Find integer $n$ such that $U(n)$ contains subgroup isomorphic to $Z_5\oplus Z_5$.

B. Show that there is an $U(n)$ containing a subgroup isomorphic to $Z_3 \oplus  Z_3$, but not isomorphic to $Z_4 \oplus  Z_4$.

Comment: What have you tried? The exercise calls for some examples. What are your thoughts on what those examples must satisfy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(A) If $n$ is prime, then you know that $U(n)$ is cyclic, and so it cannot have a non-cyclic subgroup. So your goal is to find a composite $n$.

The simplest such would be $n = pq$, where $p, q$ are prime and $p\neq q$. Now
$$
U(n) \cong U(p) \times U(q) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p-1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q-1}
$$
To find a subgroup of the form $\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_5$, one can look for two primes $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
5\mid (p-1), \text{ and } 5\mid (q-1)
$$
So you list down numbers of the form $(5k+1)$ until you hit two distinct primes : 11, and 31.

Hence, $U(341) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}\times \mathbb{Z}_{30}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_5$.

Now can you try the same thing for (B)?

Comment: @ Prahlad Vaidyanathan--In part(B) we can take p=7 & q=13, so I get $U(91)$ is isomorphic to $Z_3 \oplus Z_3$. Now how to check that this is not isomorphic to $Z_4 \oplus Z_4$.

Comment: An abelian group has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ iff it has two elements of order 4 which are not powers of each other. Check that no two such elements exist in $U(91)$

Comment: nice answer @PrahladVaidyanathan